# Convert sRGB PDF to CMYK PDF

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript, imagemagick-convert, cmyk

How can I convert sRGB PDF to CMYK PDF on Linux Command Line, by keeping small file sizes and high qualtiy.

If I use imagemagic convert, I get the correct colors with this command.:

```
convert -profile /usr/share/ghostscript/9.05/iccprofiles/srgb.icc -profile /usr/share/ghostscript/9.05/iccprofiles/default_cmyk.icc sRGB.pdf default_cmyk.pdf
```

But this does not keep a sharp image. If I use convert qualtiy options to solve this, the file size blow up.

The qualtiy of the image is much better, if I use GhostScript.

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOCACHE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceCMYK -sOutputICCProle=/usr/share/ghostscript/9.05/iccprofiles/default_cmyk.icc -dOverrideICC  -sOutputFile=gs_default_cmyk.pdf sRGB.pdf
```

But then colors does not fit.

How can I get the colors I get with convert and the line accuracy and file size I get with GhostScript?

Comment: Firstly don't use '-dOverrideICC', '-sOutputICCProle' (which should be -sOutputICCProfile anyway), or '-dProcessColorModel'. Use the current version of Ghostscript (you don't say what version you are ucrrently suing) and explain what you mean by 'colours does not fit'. Examples are always useful. Since 'convert almost certainly renders to an image and then embeds the image in a PDF< you can't get the **same** colours in a GS-produced PDF file, but you haven't explained what's wrong with the colours you *do* get.

Comment: I use GS 9.05. If we make the conversion with convert, then we get the color conversion we want. So the question must be: How can we get the same color conversion with GS?

Comment: Use different profiles. Seriously, how can I possibly answer this question ? You have not supplied an example, or even images, of what you perceive to be a problem, nor a Ghostscript command line, nor any information on the colour management you are employing with Ghostscript. You are also using a 4 year old version. The first thing you should do is update to something less archaic (current version is 9.19). If after that you still have some kind of problem then we can discuss it, but you are going to have to come up with some information from your end. Something more than 'I want....'